# Reference tag pollutes modules using Typescript

Tags: reference, module, typescript

Let's say that I have file `lib.ts` which contains

```
/// <reference path="assets/webgl.d.ts" />
export var wrapper = 4;
```

Then I have file `main.ts` which contains

```
import lib = module("lib");
// when I hit space here, I see all the `webgl.d.ts` declarations
```

How can I stop `webgl.d.ts` polluting all the modules that load `lib.ts`? `webgl.d.ts` should be visible **only** inside of the `lib.ts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this isn't what you want to happen, this is actually how the TypeScript language is documented to work. From the [TypeScript Language Specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf):

> Any files included as dependencies in turn have their references
>   analyzed in a transitive manner until all dependencies have been
>   determined.

So the TypeScript compiler is designed to walk the dependency tree for you.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Well, the result for me is that I cannot use `webgl.d.ts` because the file is too long and it completely slows down / freezes the VS IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure that the specification covers this mix of references and external modules: for imported modules, walking dependencies does not mean polluting importers, for referenced code it does. Mixed usage seems to fall into the gap.